# Unable to publish a project into windows azure staging environment

Tags: azure, azure-deployment

Initially,i publish a project into windows Azure staging environment using visual studio 2010(windows Azure SDK v1.6), i got warning exceptions like,

> Warning: There was no endpoint listening at https://management.core.windows.net//services/hostedservices//deploymentslots/Staging that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
>   Warning: There was no endpoint listening at https://management.core.windows.net//services/hostedservices//deploymentslots/Staging that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
>   Warning: The HTTP request to 'https://management.core.windows.net/<>/services/hostedservices/service/deploymentslots/Staging' has exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:01:00. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.
>   Warning: The HTTP request to 'https://management.core.windows.net/<>/services/hostedservices/service/deploymentslots/Staging' has exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:01:00. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

After that, i cancel & Remove that deployment, then again i publish a same project, this time i am not getting any warning message and error, but the deployment not completing yet(last 4 hours)..still its running..so pls help me where i made mistake?

if you need any information for the issue, pls let me know.

Thanks advance!!.

Comment: have you tried to "package" the project and deploy it manually via the Azure portal?

Comment: I have to use, deploying worker role into Azure via Visual Studio SDK1.6 only. i didn't try using "Package".